# Possible neutral problem - Utility side vs. Load Side?

Tags: circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, neutral

PLEASE NOTE:  UPDATED CIRCUIT NUMBERING FROM 12 & 14 to 14 & 16

I would greatly appreciate your help with trying to diagnose a problem that appears to be an open neutral. In my kitchen I have three circuits (C). They are numbers 14, 16, and 32 in my panel. C32 is a single GFCI circuit that powers only my microwave. When I use the microwave the voltage on C16 drops several volts from 120 to around 116.  If I use another high current appliance (electric kettle) on C16 the V drops to 114-112. Add something else and it's dropped below 110V.  I've pulled the receptacles and checked the connections and also used the little plug in tester and it shows they are all wired correctly.

Each of these three circuits also run through a manually switched Reliance generator panel. Today the power went out and I started the generator and switched the Reliance panel to the generator.  I checked the voltage on C16 and it was 122V. I then turned on the microwave and the voltage on C16 started rising to 130V.  In place of the microwave I then let the Well Pump (240V) kick on. After it started the voltage on C16 remained at 122V (running on the generator).

The last thing I tried this evening (back on house power) was to run the microwave on C14.  In this case the voltage on C16 rose a little from 120V to 122V. Given that the two breakers are adjacent to one another I'm guessing they are on opposite legs in the panel.

I did check every connection on the neutral bar, ground bar, and every breaker, as well as the main neutral wire (multi-stranded aluminum) in the panel.

The other issue of concern is that my electric bill is about double that of my neighbors.  I do have 3 teenagers and electric hot water so that could be part of the problem.   :)

A friend who pointed me to the neutral problem told me that I may have recourse with the power company if the neutral problem is on their side. We have been through several microwaves, etc. My outside feed is from a pole not underground.

I apologize for the long winded description but I'm hoping it shed some light as to where the problem may be.

My question is this:

How can I determine if the problem is on circuit side of the panel or the meter side?  If I can determine it's on the meter side, I was advised to call an electrician to check the meter connections before calling the utility company as I don't know how apt they would be to take responsibility if it is on their side.

Here is a photograph of the circuit breaker panel:

[image: Cutler Hammer Circuit Panel cover removed]

Photo of Panel Label:

[image: Cutler Hammer Panel Label]
Photo of Reliance ProTran Switch Model 31410CRK:

[image: Reliance ProTran]
I have checked all the connections for the transfer switch and I have added a tie bar to switch both legs of a MWBC between B-G on the transfer switch which are circuits 6 and 8 in the panel.  Otherwise everything is exactly as specified.

Comment: I would start with a call to the power company - you may find them more accommodating about checking this out than you appear to be assuming.

Comment: What type of panel do you have?  Better yet, can you provide us with photos of it?

Comment: It is a Cutler Hammer / Eaton panel - House was built in 1962 but I don't know if the panel is original.  I've also removed any aluminum wiring that was in the house when we moved in.  I'll post a pic as well.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It is a Cutler Hammer / Eaton panel - House was built in 1962 but I don't know if the panel is original.  I've also removed any aluminum wiring that was in the house when we moved in.  I'll post a pic as well.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have a picture with the cover off but I'm still trying to figure out how to post it.

Comment: Just upload the photo to [imgur](http://imgur.com) and link it in a comment, we can do the rest.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel [link](http://i.imgur.com/JMEau3n.jpg)  I hope this works...

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks.  I'd like to try to figure out if it's inside my house before having them come out.  Not sure if they charge if it's my issue.

Comment: @Eric Mark, in the electrical business, we always get the utility co. to check first.  It's always free, as opposed to a hired electrician.

Comment: Also, can you provide a photo of the panel's label? (It should be on the inside of the door)

Comment: I like my CH panels.   However you must have the space numbers wrong.  CH numbers left to right top to bottom.  Space 12 is the bottom half of `DRYER 1`.  Anyway if these breakers are adjacent, they are on opposite poles, which suggests to me they **may** be a multi-wire branch circuit or MWBC.  These share a neutral, so the neutral problem could be local to the MWBC.  The way to tell is check other unrelated circuits for hot-neutral voltage changes.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I added a photo of the panel label but the circuit descriptions may be inaccurate in places.  I also updated the two circuits that I had numbered incorrectly.  If you are asking to see what is on the actual circuits I can do that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Harper  Thanks.  Yes I screwed up the numbering. I updated the description above.  The 2 circuits are 14 and 16.  Under what conditions would I measure the hot-neutral voltage changes?  The load (microwave) that I initially noticed was causing the voltage change is on C32 which is a single GFCI direct to the panel.

Comment: Thought so.  I just looked at the bottom conduit.  I think I found your problem LOL.

Comment: @Harper The bottom conduit goes to a Reliance #31410 CRK Manual Transfer Switch for Portable Generators.  The Switch is prewired through the conduit. It comes as a complete setup. There is only one neutral which had me wondering.  There may be an issue with load balancing but when it is switched to generator they are all done at the same time.

Comment: @Harper  I checked all the connections, circuits, etc. per the Reliance manual and everything is wired correctly.  There is one MWBC and it is between circuits B & G on the Transfer Switch (6 & 8 in the main panel).  Both circuits are for lighting and bedroom outlets.  The bath notated is only lighting.  It doesn't appear that the transfer switch is the issue.

Comment: But stop.  If the furnace and microwave both want power, where do they get it from? I see the line wire they use, but through what path does the power return?  I.e. What do they use for a neutral?  Think it through.

Comment: @Harper  I understand what you are saying and I don't know the internal wiring of the transfer switch.  I believe the manual says that when the switch is on the utility side it is using the panel breaker so I'm guessing that the line wire just passes through the transfer switch and its using breaker panel neutral.

Comment: But consider the neutral wire on the problem circuit.  What is its path back to the bare aluminum neutral lead in the main panel?   It doesn't hop there by magic, there must be a path of continuous wire.  What is the path?   Ok, now what is the path for other circuits on that same side of the generator swirch panel?

Comment: The way it is wired leads me to believe that the transfer panel is just a longer loop for the line wire and the neutral is only used on generator power.  For each circuit the line wire is removed from the panel breaker and connected to a wire (labeled with a specific transfer breaker) and then a corresponding wire comes from the transfer switch and connects to the panel breaker creating a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Both your circuits' hots are red wires... Ok... But I follow them, and several pairs of wires are cable-tied together which suggests 240V or MWBCs, ok..., and they both disappear into the bottom conduit, where--

What, the, actual, heck...???

--  there's like 20 red and black wires going into this fat conduit, **And Only One Neutral!**

You can't do that!!!  A bajillion circuits can't share a neutral!   Each hot gets its own neutral, except for MWBCs where two hots share 1 neutral.  You can't have a MMMMMMMMWBC!

You also can't put more than 9 wires in a conduit without derating (using thicker wire).

This is either a total nightmare, or needs some serious explaining.   Who did this work?

Comment: The bottom conduit goes to a Reliance ProTran #31410 CRK  Manual Transfer Switch for portable generators.  It's prewired that way.

Comment: WTF? Reliance is responsible for that nightmare? *sigh*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Is this a design issue or an install problem?  I'll admit to doing the install but it was per the manual.  Unless I've messed up by including only part of an MWBC?

Comment: I don't know *what* is going on inside that box....guess it's time to go Googling for its manual!

Comment: I wonder if the solitary neutral is only needed by internal circuitry in the transfer switch, not by the outside world...?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can link the manual if it will help.  I've also added a pic of the circuit layout.  I'm wondering if I have either part of a MWBC or I have the circuit layout in the ProTran incorrectly balanced.

Comment: @EricMark -- I was able to find the manual without a hitch

Comment: Guys!! Calm down!.... Those transfer panels are completely legal and very common. I've installed dozens myself. ...... The neutral is only for the receptacle and/or meters on the transfer panel. The circuits still original in the main panel and that is where their neutrals are terminated. The transfer panel switches are just wired thru the DPST switches, choosing either the breaker or push-button breaker on the transfer panel.

Comment: Also, the flex is under 24" so derating is a non-issue.

Comment: So you're saying the circuits come into the main panel, and the transfer panel is essentially a *switch loop*.  OK, that works for me, although it leaves the OP problem still a mystery. (the problem looks like a weak undersized neutral.)  Also, when it's on generator mode, where do those circuits get neutral?  Does the generator supply its neutral to the panel via one of those fat neutral wires?  How does it handle worst-case imbalance (all loads on one leg at capacity, loads on the other leg off)?

Comment: @Harper  That's correct.  This is the URL for the documentation which does discuss the neutral.  "http://www.reliancecontrols.com/Documents/ProTran%20Instructions.pdf"  I do believe that when everything is on line power the transfer switch should not contribute to the neutral issue so I'm not sure how to hunt down the problem beyond what I've done so far, if it is on my side of the meter.

Comment: That explains the wire-nuts in the panel.  I would remove those "switch loops" and reconnect those circuits directly -- purely as a diagnostic aid to see what happens.  I have a feeling the problem will go away, but I can't explain why yet.  If the problem remains, you can definitively exclude the panel.  The documentation says far too little about neutrals, particularly how generator neutral is fed to the circuits the generator is powering.